# What is the size of large notification icons?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-icons

There are two functions to set notification icon setSmallIcon & setLargeIcon in NotificationCompat.Builder

I know that the small notification icon for mdpi density is 24x24dpi.

But what is the size of large notification icon for mdpi density?

Thank you.

Comment: When you want to know that to be sure what size your large notification icon needs, it may be irrelevant. Icons will be imported in different densities in Android Studio and android should pick the correct density for each device.

Comment: Hello Ahmed. Did my answer help you understand what the different notification sizes are and the dpi density associated with them?

Answer (score 6):

For every device, you can use [android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen#notification_large_icon_height) and [android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen#notification_large_icon_width) to get the appropriate size for the device:

```
int largeIconHeight = context.resources
    .getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height)
int largeIconWidth = context.resources
    .getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width)
```

In practice, all devices use a square shape, so the two dimensions are always the same.

Answer (score 1):

For `setSmallIcon` refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar

Also the best way to create the icon is with the asset manger (file -> new -> image asset) in android studio, otherwise the icon might not dim properly.

For the `setLargeIcon` I never used anything larger than 192x192 at xxxhdpi. It's pretty much a standard 48dp icon.